# Ansible command for kubectl get openshiftapiserver

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

How do i convert the below kubectl command into ansible role/command to run on a cluster?

```
kubectl get openshiftapiserver \
  -o=jsonpath='{range .items[0].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Encrypted")]}{.reason}{"\n"}{.message}{"\n"}'
```

Below ansible playbook format doesn't seems to be correct one:

```
- name: check apiserver
  command: kubectl get openshiftapiserver -o=jsonpath='{range .items[0].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Encrypted")]}{.reason}{"\n"}{.message}{"\n"}'
```

Comment: In what way is the ansible task not working? Are you getting an error message? Or some sort of unexpected output? This command seems to work just fine for me in a playbook; it returns the same output as the shell command you show at the beginning of your question. In your example playbook task you don't appear to be capturing the output of the command, which is perhaps your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The task you've shown seems to do exactly what you want.  For example, consider the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: >-
        kubectl get openshiftapiserver
        -o=jsonpath='{range .items[0].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Encrypted")]}{.reason}{"\n"}{.message}{"\n"}'
      register: res

    - debug:
        var: res.stdout
```

If you run this, it produces the output:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "res.stdout": "EncryptionDisabled\nEncryption is not enabled"
}
```

That's the same output produced by running the `kubectl get ...` command manually from the command line.

---

You could also parse the response in Ansible to generate slightly nicer output:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: >-
        kubectl get openshiftapiserver
          -o=jsonpath='{.items[0].status.conditions[?(@.type=="Encrypted")]}'
      register: res

    - set_fact:
        encrypted: "{{ res.stdout|from_json }}"

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "message: {{ encrypted.message }}"
          - "reason: {{ encrypted.reason }}"
```

This would produce:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "message: Encryption is not enabled",
        "reason: EncryptionDisabled"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use `/` for especial characters:

```
---
- name: check Zabbix-agent IP and upload to Zabbix-server
  hosts: mylocalhost
  tasks:
    - name: run kubectl command
      command: "kubectl get openshiftapiserver -o=jsonpath='{range .items[0].status.conditions[?(@.type==\"Encrypted\")]}{.reason}{\"\n\"}{.message}{\"\n\"}'"
```

For more info view: [YAML Syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html)

Comment: I don't see how changing from `command` to `shell` is going to help in this particular situation; for simple commands like this the modules are functionally identical.

Comment: I used shell  + / for especial characters, read all command before comment and assign -1.

Comment: I don't think using `shell` changes this at all, and typically just introduces complications because now you need to escape shell metacharacters. You should always use `command` unless you specifically require shell features  like pipes, output redirection, etc.